# Can estimated value plus one standard deviation be less than true value in a synthetic experiment?

Tags: regression, bayesian, standard-deviation, inverse-problem

I perform a synthetic calculation and then an inversion, that is, I have actual value in the synthetic calculation and I estimate it in the inverse problem stage. The inverse problem gives me the estimation of the actual value and its standard deviation. However, the estimated value plus the standard deviation is less than the actual value. Is it possible? should I use two or more standard deviations? why?

Details: My synthetic problem is $y=A(x) + n$. The model parameter $x$, the forward mapping $A$, and noise $n$, are known in the synthetic calculations, $y$ is unknown. I can compute $y$. Then I use that vector $y$ in another problem, that is, the inversion, to estimate $x$ and its standard deviation by a Monte Carlo method. Let's call it $x^{est}$ with the estimated standard deviation of $\sigma^{est}$. Now, $x^{est} + \sigma^{est} < x$. It seems to me that it is not a good and correct $\sigma^{est}$. Shouldn't estimated mean plus estimated standard deviation cover actual value?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean exactly by the estimated standard deviation. If you e.g. mean the standard error for a regression coefficient, then estimate +- standard error should cover the true value of the regression coefficient about 68% of the time. And that's when everything is perfect (i.e. you assumed the exact true data generating model as your analysis model, no issues from normal approximation with small sample size...).

Comment: I am not good at statistics. If I change "estimated standard deviation" to "standard error", would the question be correct?